# Does Amazon EC2 allow to install tools?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

In case of dedicates servers, we are allowed to install any software. Does Amazon EC2 instance  allow to install tools?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, EC2 is like a virtual machine that create to your own spec, and then request copies of it to be started by Amazon.

There is lots more information on this site:

http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/

http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs

Answer (score 2):

Yes, EC2 provides the same as a dedicated server plus you can replicate the image and start multiple instances.

Answer (score 2):

Your question has already been answered. But to even illustrate the point futher. Amazon EC2 even allows you to setup your own operating system.

As far as I can tell it must be a unix/linux operating system, but you can go so far as to build your own kernel

limitless possibilites here.